# ESP8266 NodeMCU src:listen Running Out of Heap Memory

Tags: lua, esp8266

Can anybody tell me why my Lua code is running out of memory. It successfully sets up the wifi connection. However, it runs out of heap memory before I connect the first client.

This is why this is imho NOT A DUP of [ESP8266 NodeMCU Running Out of Heap Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315548/esp8266-nodemcu-running-out-of-heap-memory)

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
station_cfg={}
station_cfg.ssid="WLAN-xxxx"
station_cfg.pwd="xxxxxxx"
wifi.sta.config(station_cfg)
wifi.sta.connect()

print(wifi.sta.getip())
RELAIS = 5
LED=0

gpio.mode(RELAIS, gpio.OUTPUT)
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
print(node.heap())
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
        print(node.heap())
--[[   ... some more stuff not relevant for the bug ...

   ]]
        client:close();
        collectgarbage();
    end)
end)
print(node.heap())
```

The output for the first heap call is 38984.
There is no output for the second heap.

Comment: Why do you think it's running out of memory? Just because your on-receive callback never fires?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the commented code to avoid confusion here.

Comment: The Esplorer tells me that the there is no heap memory left

Comment: What NodeMCU version does this run on? This code looks odd anyway because it doesn't wait until WiFi setup is fully completed (remember, `wifi.sta.connect()` is non-blocking).